# Help finding the name of a literary device

Tags: literary-techniques, literary-device

## Circumstance/Background

To express the surety of a particular outcome, a future/forecasted event is spoken of as if it has already transpired.

### Question

The aforementioned literary style foreshadows the said event; does the *manner* in which the foreshadowing occurs have a particular name?

#### Examples

> *The victory is mine*

Though a victory has not been secured

> *Rome has fallen*

Though the battle is not complete

Comment: could [fatalism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fatalism) fit the purpose? FWIW Roman stoicism was fatalistic as I understand it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procatalepsis

Comment: @whanrott Fatalism is usually about bad/undesired results, and contrasts with optimism. You wouldn't use it when you look forward to victory.

Comment: @Barmar - [Fatalism](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fatalism) "The belief that all events are predetermined and therefore inevitable". People who believe in fate do so without prejudice about whether the fate will be good or bad. I do agree that people usually _use_ fatalistic in a negative or pessimistic way but that's not its' only meaning.

Comment: @Bookeater - Thank you! Finally I have an obscure word to describe a _question talker_. :-)

Comment: @whanrott I suspect the negative interpretation is common because it sounds like the word "fatal".

Comment: Is this not anticipation?

Either way, *surety* is about warranty or insurance. What you prolly meant was *certainty*.